# Flag gaps and new entries in time series database - customer attrition & new customers

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to flag new customers and attritted customers in my database.  The objective is to have a pretty simple flat table where I can just pull "new customers" and "lost customers" for a given business and a given year.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
BUSINESS, CUSTOMER, YEAR
Business X, Customer A, 2001
Business X, Customer A, 2002
Business X, Customer A, 2003
Business X, Customer B, 2004
Business X, Customer B, 2005
Business Y, Customer A, 2004
```

And I would like to put two new columns in my table such that I flag if a customer is "NEW" in that year, or is "GONE" the next year for that business line.  So the end result should look like this:

```
BUSINESS, CUSTOMER, YEAR, NEW, GONE
Business X, Customer A, 2001, NEW, NULL
Business X, Customer A, 2002, NULL, NULL
Business X, Customer A, 2003, NULL, GONE
Business X, Customer B, 2004, NEW, NULL
Business X, Customer B, 2005, NULL, GONE
Business Y, Customer A, 2004, NEW, NULL
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help.  I am working on this in SQL but also in Google Cloud Dataprep, and am a terrible coder and very open to brute force techniques!!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks Strawberry.  To be clear, the second example "I think" is the MCVE?  It's what I want to get as the result in the end.  I edited the question to be more clear, but I am new here so could still be very wrong...

Comment: Newness is normal. 'I think' the linked answer is self-explanatory

Comment: Why do you want to create two columns `NEW` and `GONE`. A single column `STATUS` could also be fine with values like `NEW`, `GONE` and `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is possible using [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), with [`Exists()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) condition.

In the first subquery, we determine if any **previous** `YEAR` exists for a particular `BUSINESS`, `CUSTOMER` and `YEAR` combination. If it `exists()`, we set the `NEW` to `NULL` (since already another row exists before this year).

In the second subquery, we determine if any **later** `YEAR` exists for a particular `BUSINESS`, `CUSTOMER` and `YEAR` combination. If it `exists()`, we set the `GONE` to `NULL` (since already another row exists after this year).

```
SELECT 
 t1.BUSINESS, 
 t1.CUSTOMER, 
 t1.YEAR, 
 IF ( EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM your_table AS t2 
             WHERE t2.BUSINESS = t1.BUSINESS AND 
                   t2.CUSTOMER = t1.CUSTOMER AND 
                   t2.YEAR < t1.YEAR 
             LIMIT 1), NULL, 'NEW' ) AS NEW, 
 IF ( EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM your_table AS t3 
             WHERE t3.BUSINESS = t1.BUSINESS AND 
                   t3.CUSTOMER = t1.CUSTOMER AND 
                   t3.YEAR > t1.YEAR 
             LIMIT 1), NULL, 'GONE' ) AS GONE
FROM your_table AS t1
```

Comment: Super helpful.  I am in the cellar for reputation so my vote didn't help raise the score.

Comment: @RedFalcon6 Please consider marking the answer as accepted answer. Click on checkmark besides the answer to turn it green. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)